# Form Action garbled, Rails 2.3.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

I seem to have a problem that I can't find the solution for myself, I hope someone can help.

I have a form defined like so:

```
<% form_for @leads do |f| %>
```

I have a resource called @leads (map.resource :leads)

But when I look in the HTML code of the page it generates, I see as a form action the following

```
<form action="/lead.%23%3Clead:0x10333e858%3E" class="edit_lead" ... etc
```

The lead.%23%3Clead:0x10333e858%3E as a form action does work, however rails doesn't know what to do with it after it updates. Does anyone know how I can make this a normal URL so that rails can redirect after the update again?

Thank you very much
Regards, Marco

Comment: I don't think I can help here right now, but the URL decodes to `lead.#<lead:0x10333e858>`.

Comment: Have you defined to_param on your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to rename your route from

```
 map.resource :leads
```

to

```
map.resources :leads
```

because you have multiple leads (and not only one -> so no "resource", its "resources")

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a singular resource you should not pass the object to the url helper, ie. `lead_path` not `lead_path(@lead)`.

However it does look like a typo and your route should be `map.resources :leads`